# Have an alert if condition is true on different id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have three tabs in my website and some content on these three tabs .
I need to have an alert when the condition is true of two variables and in presence of on that particular id.
Please see the code below,

```
<div id="acc" class="container_wide">

   <ul>
    <li><a href="#tb-1" class="first_mn">1st</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tb-2" class="second_mn">2nd</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tb-3" class="third_mn">3rd</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div class ="weeks" id="tb-1">
   // some contents 
   </div>

   <div class ="weeks" id="tb-2">
   // some contents 
   </div>

   <div class ="weeks" id="tb-3">
   // some contents 
   </div>
</div>
```

My two variables are

```
<script>
total = 0;
max = 0;
// some codes to increase the values of total and max
</script>
```

I have tried as

```
<script>
jQuery(".container_wide .second_mn").click(function(){

  if(jQuery(".first_mn").length && total > max ){
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    alert("Not saved");
    }
});
  if(jQuery(".second_mn").data('clicked')) {
     alert("Not saved");
}
</script>
```

Similarly, i need to have the same function by clicking the all tabs

The above code doesn't work out for me.
can anyone please recommend me the solution for it.

Comment: I find your question to be Unclear.  Please improve the explanation of the logic and setup something that we can actually test with.

Comment: @mickmackusa Vote accordingly then; I have.

Answer (score 0):

1. Need to subscribe the event after the content loaded

// Document ready

```
$(function() {

    jQuery(".container_wide .tab").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked. container_wide "+$(this).html());
    if(jQuery(this).length && total > max ){
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
        alert("Not saved");
        }
    });

  if(jQuery(".second_mn").data('clicked')) {
     alert("Not saved");
    } 
});
```

2. since you want same function to be called, you can add the "tab" class to all the li tage and add the onclick event to it.

> ```
>    <ul>
>     <li><a href="#tb-1" class="tab irst_mn">1st</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#tb-2" class="tab second_mn">2nd</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#tb-3" class="tab third_mn">3rd</a></li>
>    </ul>
>
>    <div class ="weeks" id="tb-1">
>    <p> some contents - 1 </p>
>    </div>
>
>    <div class ="weeks" id="tb-2">
>    <p> some contents - 2 </p>
>    </div>
>
>    <div class ="weeks" id="tb-3">
>   <p> some contents - 3 </p>
>    </div>
> </div>
> ```